# How to handle frontier between typeclass and inheritance usage

Tags: scala, typeclass

I am getting frustrated because I don't know how to handle the frontier between my typesafe  code and the external API which uses polymorphism and inheritance.

My flow is the following. I receive an entry value of class Class1, which I use to retrieve from an external service an item of Class Class2. Then I need to subtype on both to obtain the runtime type of them and resolve the implicit. However, this is not possible because of type erasure.

```
trait Typeclass1[A, B] {
  def hash(a: A, b: B): String
}

trait Typeclass2[A, B] {
  def hash(a: A, b: B): B
}

trait Entity

trait MyEntity1

trait MyEntity2

object db {
  def load(any:Any):Entity = new Entity{}
}


class MyClass[T](t: T, a: String) {

  def apply(timeout: Long): T = {
    val loadFromDB = db.load(t)
    loadFromDB match {
      case myEntity1: MyEntity1 => applyTypeSafe(myEntity1)
      case myEntity2: MyEntity2 => applyTypeSafe(myEntity2)
    }
  }


  def applyTypeSafe[C](c: C)(implicit typeClass1: Typeclass1[C, T], typeclass2: Typeclass2[C, T]): (String, T) = {
    typeClass1.hash(c, t) -> typeclass2.hash(c, t)
  }
}
```

I am wondering what is the right pattern to develop this frontier layer.  I would probably need a type-constructor for my typeclass to provide at at  the constructor of MyClass... or maybe to totally rethinkg my design?

Comment: I do not see the problem. Which types get erased? As far as I can see you should be able to pattern match reliably on `loadFromDB` and then you have recovered all the type info the DB layer looses.

Answer (score 0):

There is no compilation issue if you add implicit definitions in scope for `MyEntity` and `MyEntity2`. For example, the code below compiles ok:

```
trait Typeclass1[A, B] { def hash(a: A, b: B): String }
trait Typeclass2[A, B] { def hash(a: A, b: B): B }

trait Entity
trait MyEntity1 extends Entity
trait MyEntity2 extends Entity

object db { def load(any:Any):Entity = new Entity {} }

implicit def MyEntity1HasTypeclass1[T] = new Typeclass1[MyEntity1, T] {
  def hash(a: MyEntity1, t: T) = a.toString
}
implicit def MyEntity1HasTypeclass2[T] = new Typeclass2[MyEntity1, T] {
  def hash(a: MyEntity1, t: T) =t
}

class MyClass[T](t: T, a: String) {
  def apply(timeout: Long): (String, T) = {
    db.load(t) match {
      case myEntity1: MyEntity1 => applyTypeSafe(myEntity1)
    }
  }
  def applyTypeSafe[C](c: C)(implicit typeClass1: Typeclass1[C, T], 
                                      typeclass2: Typeclass2[C, T]): (String, T) = {
    typeClass1.hash(c, t) -> typeclass2.hash(c, t)
  }
}
```

Comment: This works as soon as you can provide a generic constructor for Typeclass1 and Typeclass2 for ALL T. but what if your typeclass exist only for specific T?

Comment: Then you can either add an upper bound to the `MyClass` parameter: `class MyClass[T <: Special]` or add a constraint to the `applyTypeSafe` method: `def applyTypeSafe[C, S](c: C)(implicit ev: S =:= Special, typeClass1,...)`